# perl using constant in regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm wondering about using constants in perl regex's.   I want to do something similar to:

```
use constant FOO => "foo"
use constant BAR => "bar"

$somvar =~ s/prefix1_FOO/prefix2_BAR/g;
```

of course, in there, `FOO` resolves to the three letters `F` `O` `O` instead of expanding to the constant.

I looked online, and someone was suggesting using either `${\FOO}`, or `@{[FOO]}` Someone else mentioned `(?{FOO})`.    I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on which of these is correct, and if there's any advantage to any of them.   Alternatively, is it better to just use a non-constant variable?  (performance is a factor in my case).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shown problem is due to those constants being barewords (built at compile time)

> Constants defined using this module cannot be interpolated into strings like variables.

In the [current implemenation](https://perldoc.perl.org/constant#TECHNICAL-NOTES) (of `constant` pragma) they are "*inlinable
subroutines*" (see <sup>†</sup> ).

This problem can be solved nicely by using a module like [Const::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/%7Eleont/Const-Fast-0.014/lib/Const/Fast.pm)

```
use Const::Fast;

const my $foo => 'FOO';
const my $bar => 'BAR';

my $var = 'prefix1_FOO_more';

$var =~ s/prefix1_$foo/prefix2_$bar/g;
```

Now they do get interpolated. Note that more complex replacements may need `/e`.

These are built at runtime so you can assign results of expressions to them. In particular, you can use the [qr operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), for example

```
const my $patt => qr/$foo/i;  # case-insensitive
```

The `qr` is the recommended way to build regex patterns. (It [interpolates](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) unless the delimiter is `'`.) The performance gain is most often tiny, but you get a proper regular expression, which can be built and used as such (and in this case a constant as well).

I recommend `Const::Fast` module over the other one readily, and in fact over all others at this time. See a [recent article](https://www.nu42.com/2016/05/perl-define-constants.html) with a detailed discussion of both. Here is a [review](http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html) of many other options.

I strongly recommend to use a constant (of your chosen sort) for things meant to be read-only. That is good for the health of the code, and of developers who come into contact with it (yourself in the proverbial six months included).

---

<sup>†</sup> These being subroutines, we need to be able to *run code* in order to have them evaluated and replaced by given values. Can't just "interpolate" (evaluate) a variable -- it's not a variable.

A way to [run code inside a string](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Miscellaneous-Usage) (which need be [interpolated](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators), so effectively double quoted) is to de-reference, where there's an expression in a block under a reference; then the expression is evaluated. So we need to first make that reference.  So either

```
say "@{ [FOO] }";  # make array reference, then dereference
```

or

```
say "${ \FOO }";   # make scalar reference then dereference
```

prints `foo`.  See the docs for why this works and for examples. Thus one can do the same inside a regex, and both in matching and replacement parts

```
s/prefix1_${\FOO}/prefix2_${\BAR}/g;
```

(or with `@{[...]}`), since they are evaluated as interpolated strings.

Which is "better"? These are tricks. There is rarely, if ever, a *need* for doing this. It has a very good chance to confuse the reader. So I just wouldn't recommend resorting to these at all.

As for `(?{ code })`, that is a regex feature, whereby *code is evaluated* inside a pattern (matching side only). It is complex and tricky and very rarely *needed*. See about it [in perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#A-bit-of-magic:-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression) and [in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?%7B-code-%7D)).

Discussing speed of these things isn't really relevant. They are certainly outside the realm of clean and idiomatic code, while you'd be hard pressed to detect runtime differences.

But if you must use one of these, I'd much rather interpolate inside a scalar reference via a trick then reach for a complex regex feature.

### Not a HASH reference

In rare cases the solution `${\FOO}` needs extra tweaking, as for `${\FOO}{6,20}`:

Perl complains

> Not a HASH reference at ...

The fix is to add extra clustering like this: `(?:${\FOO}){6,20}`

Comment: Shouldn't `qr/foo/i` be `qr/$foo/i`?

Comment: @U.Windl Indeed, it makes for a better example using a variable, changed w/ a comment. Thank you

Comment: Well typically you don't know how a `FOO`look like if you want it to repeat. Plain `(` and `)` will capture strings, possibly breaking any capture groups that might be inside `FOO`. I'm not sure I understood your last sentence.

Comment: @U.Windl  Ah ... that was about a pattern inside regex, not in general. (duh -- for some reason I thought that the edit is about the `@{[...]}` trick (or with a scalar, `${\...}`) used in a double-quote context elsewhere, not in regex).  OK, my comment is off then, will remove it once you've seen this...

Comment: @U.Windl  Deleted that comment

Answer (score 9):

There's not much in the way of reasons to use a constant over a variable. It doesn't make a great deal of difference - `perl` will compile a regex anyway.

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

use constant FOO => "foo";
use constant BAR => "bar";

my $FOO_VAR = 'foo';
my $BAR_VAR = 'bar';

sub pattern_replace_const {
   my $somvar = "prefix1_foo test";
   $somvar =~ s/prefix1_${\FOO}/prefix2_${\BAR}/g;
}

sub pattern_replace_var {
   my $somvar = "prefix1_foo test";
   $somvar =~ s/prefix1_$FOO_VAR/prefix2_$BAR_VAR/g;
}

cmpthese(
   1_000_000,
   {  'const' => \&pattern_replace_const,
      'var'   => \&pattern_replace_var
   }
);
```

Gives:

```
          Rate const   var
const 917095/s    --   -1%
var   923702/s    1%    --
```

Really not enough in it to worry about.

However it may be worth noting - you can compile a regex with [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) and do it that way, which - provided the RE is static - might improve performance (but it might not, because perl *can* detect static regexes, and does that itself.

```
    Rate      var    const compiled
var      910498/s       --      -2%      -9%
const    933097/s       2%       --      -7%
compiled 998502/s      10%       7%       --
```

With code like:

```
my $compiled_regex = qr/prefix1_$FOO_VAR/;
sub compiled_regex { 
    my $somvar = "prefix1_foo test";
    $somvar =~ s/$compiled_regex/prefix2_$BAR_VAR/g;
}
```

Honestly though - this is a micro optimisation. The regex engine is fast compared to your code, so don't worry about it. If performance is critical to your code, then the correct way of dealing with it is *first* write the code, and *then* profile it to look for hotspots to optimise.

Comment: I think the point of constants is not that they may be faster than variables, but that they are *constant*.

Comment: In my particular case, the values I'm using are indeed constant.   I was thinking of moving to constants for this reason along with the potential performance benifits.

Comment: Also constants may be used to assemble several regexps using common components. That may improve maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

According to PerlMonk, you better create an already-interpolated string if you are concerned about performance:

```
use constant PATTERN => 'def';
my $regex = qr/${\(PATTERN)}/; #options such as /m can go here.
if ($string =~ regex) { ... }
```

Here is the link to the [whole discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=104059).

Comment: I wonder: Does that answer the question (`${\FOO}` vs. `@{[FOO]}` vs. `(?{FOO})`)?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```perl
use constant FOO => "foo";
use constant BAR => "bar";

my $var =~ s/prefix1_${\FOO}/prefix2_${\BAR}/g;
```

Credit: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=293323